# How can I determine which rust target to compile to by looking at a windows computer?

Tags: rust

I am compiling a rust application that will be statically linked and then placed on an external server. What settings, config, or table should I look up to find the correct compile target? For most modern windows server and computers, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc should work just fine, but I wanted to know if there was a more concrete way of figuring this out.

[Here the rustup docs](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows.html) mention windows installation and considerations, but not how to figure out the target.

Comment: The `x86_64` is the processor architecture. For conventional computers ("conventional" is here defined as "what a non-programmer imagines when you say the word "computer"), it's always going to be `x86_64`. Raspberry Pi's, smartphones, and lots of embedded computers have ARM chips, and occasionally you'll see other architectures like MIPS. Given that you mention an external server, check the specs on the processor, as some lightweight headless systems will use ARM to be more energy efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to the system you are building for and run `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`. This will give us information about the CPU architecture that can help us decide.

According to the win32 documentation, it will be a value of `AMD64`, `IA64`, `ARM64`, or `x86`. Conveniently these line up with the available windows rust targets. I can find all of the rust targets by running `rustup target list` and looking for ones with windows in the name. Here is that output on my machine:

```
$ rustup target list | grep windows
aarch64-pc-windows-msvc
i586-pc-windows-msvc
i686-pc-windows-gnu
i686-pc-windows-msvc
x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

For the values of `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`, we can more or less approximate which is which by just googling them.

- `AMD64`: This is just another name for `x86_64` so we need to use either `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` or `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`.
- `IA64`:  ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ Rust is built on top of LLVM. `IA64` has reached its end of life and not much hardware uses it so [LLVM decided not to support this architecture](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2009-July/024066.html). I think `gcc` probably does support it, but we're already out of luck when it comes to using Rust.
- `ARM64`: This corresponds to the `aarch64` architecture so we should use `aarch64-pc-windows-msvc`.
- `x86`: This actually means we are running in 32bit mode so we need to choose either `i686-pc-windows-msvc` or `i686-pc-windows-gnu`.

As for `i586-pc-windows-msvc`, it refers to the older I5 Pentium architecture. It should be compatible with the newer `i686` and `x86_64` architectures, but may or may not be as performant. I would avoid it unless you are working with older hardware and need compatibility. I am also assuming it will not be compatible with windows 11 due to the new 64bit requirement.

As for the difference between `msvc` and `gnu`, you get to pick. I imagine `msvc` will be easier to work with, but I have not tried to use the `gnu` version.